# Word Rich Text Content Control and Highlighing

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I'm having some issues with combining Rich Text Content Controls and Highlighting in Word (Office 365)

We have several templates where the user is prompted to replace text with more detailed information relevent to the end user. The locations for this text is highlighted yellow using the *Highlighter* tool.

Some users have requested a more streamlined way of replacing the text and setting it to the Normal paragraph text

A *Rich Text Content Control* seems to answer the question. However, if I set the highlighted text as a control, then click the "..." button to select the text, and type my replacement, the first character is highlighted

Any pointers?

Comment: Does the highlight color have to be yellow? What if was a light grey?

Comment: Another question, what is the length of the text being replaced? Is it a simple prompt such as “Enter more information here” or are you wanting to replace multiple sentences or paragraphs of highlighted text?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was *almost* there.

I thought that I had replaced the placeholder text in the Rich Text Controls correctly, but it turns out that there is an oddity in Word where selecting all the default text and replacing it *doesn't* set the placeholder correctly.
(see about halfway down here https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/modify_cc_placeholder_text.html)

Clicking the second character, typing the required text, then deleting character 1, does set the placeholder as needed. It also selects all the text to be replace on clicking the text, not just the "..." button.